# Two packages of the same jar , logging and overlapping content on the same log file

Tags: java, logging, log4j

I have a jar with multiple src packages and a single log4j xml(for appenders and loggers configuration, so the log file is only one here).
There is a huge inflow of requests being processed sometimes and two of the packages are logging to the same log file and hence the contents is being overridden.
Since i am new to Java and log4j stuff, can you please help me so that this overlapping scenario can be avoided?

Comment: Log to a database not to a file.

Comment: @harmonica141 Thank you but Logging to a db is not possible as per the current architecture.Plus monitoring of log files is comparatively easier.Any other alternative?

Comment: On which platform do you share the log file for the instances logging?